# Python unittest/test fixture testing if module is loaded

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm using another SO recommendation for importing `simplejson`, which reads as follows:

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

However, in writing my unittest to see if "one of the json modules" has in fact been imported, I'm stuck in the circular nightmare that is my own design!  /sigh.

```
class AreAllModulesLoaded(unit.TestCase):
    """Test to make sure all modules are loaded"""
    def test_json(self):
        try:
            self.assertTrue("simplejson" in sys.modules)
        except:
            try:
                self.assertTrue("json" in sys.modules)
            except AssertionError:
                raise
```

I thought something like this would have worked, however, on inspection of the `unittest.failUnless` or `unittest.assertTrue` (I have tried both), it raises the failure and the test stops (it's failing because I am causing the failure by only loading `json` instead of `simplejson`)...

My intended goal is I want my unittest to confirm that EITHER json or simplejson was loaded.  How might I go about this?

I have thought about capturing "truthiness" prior to assertion, and then only pass "True" or "False", but that doesn't feel right for unittesting only because I thought that this should have been part the unittest proper rather than a work-around (that's my opinion, maybe you feel differently).  For example, I had thought about doing something like (python-esque pseduoish code):

```
_simplejsonLoaded = "simplejson" in sys.modules
_jsonLoaded = "json" in sys.modules

self.assertTrue(_simplejsonLoaded or _jsonLoaded)
```

(I am new to formal unittesting - so, if something seems crazy here please let me know).

Other information:

- Im using Python 2.6 (for work reasons - can't change that)
- Windows and Linux

Comment: upvote just because of the use of `the circular nightmare that is my own design!`

Comment: Btw, why can't you say assertTrue('simplejson' in modules or 'json' in modules)?

Comment: @Himanshu, that works!  I didn't think to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the try/except stuff in the TestCase

```
import sys
import unittest
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_json(self):
        if ('json' in sys.modules or 'simplejson' in sys.modules):
            self.assert_(True, "some kind of json loaded")
        else:
            self.fail()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: That also works!  I knew it would be something terribly simple but I just got caught looking at it differently which obviously wasn't working.  Why use `self.assert_` instead of `self.failUnless` or some other variant?  And, what added value does the message with the assert add to the test?  Is this used for `Nose` or similar application?

Comment: I'm using assert_ as I write tests for python 2.5, 2.6 it's just a habit, failUnless sounds good.  The messages add value to the test in the same way that comments add value to source code, more information where it is needed

Answer (score 1):

Well, the question is whether you really care which particular library you have imported. When you import `simplejson as json` then you `json` symbol in `sys.modules` as well, and that's what really matters, right? Of course, you can then check whether the imported `json` library has all methods and properties required for your own program, but that’s another issue. So, isn’t the correct definition of the test just:

```
import sys
import my_own_module

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_json(self):
        self.assertIn('json', sys.modules,
                      "json API not loaded")
```